# What's the best way to organize a display list using AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I tried organizing a display list by using setChildIndex(player, numChildren - 5); etc.

But it get's all mixed up with the other objects and sometimes shows on top or bottom of expected.

Is there a good way to keep the objects organized, so it can be displayed line by line from top to bottom?

Thanks.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: if you have MovieClips created or draged from library, you should use layers...

Comment: layers don't have anything to do with the display list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep them in an array, sort or move them as you want inside the array and then just do `addChild()` for each element of the array.